# Firebase data sorting by date stamp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ia am working on an app that receives `datamessages` with `timestamp` in the format `"yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss"`. here is the JSON data  format.

```
"NOT20170828132901" : 
{
          "code" : "Your order status has been updated to Rejected",
          "date" : "2017/08/28 13:29:01",
          "title" : "Order update  SPB20170825095233542"
}
```

i want to sort the *NOTNUMBER* based on the latest timestamp. I tried with `limitToLast(i)` and also `limitToFirst(i)` but in vein. The result is  **Ascending order**. Iwant the datestamp to be sorted in **Descending order**. I also tried using `startAt(futuredatestamp).endAt(pastdatestamp)` but not working. I want to sort in this ay:

```
"NOT20170828140827" : {
          "code" : "Your order status has been updated to Rejected",
          "date" : "2017/08/28 14:08:27",
          "title" : "Order update  SPB20170825095233542"
        },
        "NOT20170828140436" : {
          "code" : "Your order status has been updated to Delivered",
          "date" : "2017/08/28 14:04:36",
          "title" : "Order update  SPB20170825095233542"
        },
        "NOT20170828132901" : {
          "code" : "Your order status has been updated to Rejected",
          "date" : "2017/08/28 13:29:01",
          "title" : "Order update  SPB20170825095233542"
        },
        "NOT20170828115852" : {
          "code" : "Your order status has been updated to Rejected",
          "date" : "2017/08/28 11:58:52",
          "title" : "Order update  SPB20170825095233542"
        },
        "NOT20170828014147" : {
          "code" : "Your order status has been updated to IN TRANSIT",
          "date" : "2017-08-28 01:41:47",
          "title" : "Order update : SPB20170825095233542"
        }
```

Little confused in using filter parameters.

Please help me. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice to save date and time in a Firebase database, is to save it as a `TIMESTAMP` using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
yourRef.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

Remember, you are saving the TIMESTAMP as a `Map` but you are retrieving it as a `long`. To get the data back, i suggest you using this method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Then the `orderBy()` method in your query will work for sure.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. But the data is in Ascending order only. I had to use the below solution by @Nyagaka Enock to reverse the recyclerview data.

Answer (score 2):

Making an assumption that you are displaying the data from Firebase in a Recyclerview, add this code.

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyActivity.this);
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

What the code above does, it reverses the contents of the recyclerview.

Comment: Thank you. Works fine to reverse the view at times. But the data not sorted in a very right way.

Comment: The code above works when you want to display the most recent updates at the top and the least recent at the bottom